# TensorFlow equivalent of np.in1d

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to do:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
b = [1,5]

result = [True,False,False,False,True,False]
```

which is the `np.in1d` function https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.in1d.html

Is there a way to implement this in TensorFlow?

Thanks!

Comment: Side note: unless this is a part of your model, there will be no advantage of implementing it with TF. This may also be the reason why TF doesn't have it. My rule of thumb: if you cannot backprop through it, don't use TensorFlow for it. This basically means that as long as you have the outputs of you model (e.g. predictions), you can safely continue with numpy or a library, to perform e.g. metrics, analysis etc. Same goes for input preprocessing. Implementing all this stuff in TF is not really possible and even when possible it is a huge work and a lot of time wasted with no clear advantage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `tf.equal` with broadcasting to form `5x2` matrix where `i,j` entry has `True` if `a[i]==b[j]` and then `tf.reduce_any` to collapse to bool vector

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
b = [1,5]
a0 = tf.expand_dims(a, 1)
b0 = tf.expand_dims(b, 0)
result = sess.run(tf.reduce_any(tf.equal(a0, b0), 1))
assert result == np.in1d(a, b)
```